# Ubuntu 14.04 boots into low-graphics mode

Tags: ubuntu

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and on my first boot I got this error:

> The system is running in low-graphics mode

so I read a help thread and I tried with updating my AMD drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

and that worked fine. But now when I reboot I just get a black screen and can't open the terminal. How I might fix this boot error?

I'm on "Try Ubuntu", I booted it from my DVD with the ISO file.
The question, [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error), is where I got the idea to update the drivers. I did get to the GRUB and I choose "failsafeX" but then again I just get a black screen from where I can do nothing.

Comment: Try reading this, http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error

Comment: here is a post that fixes your problem http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2014/07/ubuntu-1404-lenovo-g510.html